# Recursively putting files in a Recycle Bin in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, recursion, path

I've written script to temporarily delete files in Unix and then save the file path so they can be restored. I have 2 functions, one to delete files, and one to delete a directory that also recursively deletes files. I have the appropriate commands to recognize the directory name and path as well as checking to see if files remain in the directory and then deleting them. At first I was getting an infinite loop but I made some changes and now, it's saying there is no such file or directory when I try to delete a directory. It still runs through the code but it doesn't delete any files. Can anyone figure this out?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #checks to see if deleted folder exists. If it doesn't, it is created.
    if [ ! -d ~/deleted ];
      then
          mkdir ~/deleted
    fi
    if [ ! -f ~/.restore.info ] ;
       then
          touch ~/.restore.info
    fi
    function recur_delete {
    dir=$1 #this will indicate the directory name only
    dirpath=$(dirname $dir) #gets the directory path
   if [ "$( ls -A /$dirpath/$dir)" ]; #determines if the directory contains files.
   then
      filename=$(find dirpath/dir -type f -printf "%f\n" | head -1)
      delete_file $filename #filename is found and sent to delete_file function to be deleted.
      recur_delete $dir #function is called again to see if more files are present.

     else
       echo Directory is empty, the directory will be deleted
       echo $dirpath/$dir >> ~/.restore.info
       rmdir ${dirpath/$dir}

fi

    }
    function delete_file {
    inode=$(stat -c%i $filename) #grabs inode # for the chosen filename.
    filename=$1 #reinitializes the variable filename as the first argument
    pwd=$(readlink -e $filename) #This gets the entire path for the chosen file
      if $interactive
        then
          if [ $verbose = true ];
                 then
                 read -p "Are you SURE you want to delete $filename ????" i_input
                     if [ $i_input == "y"  ] || [ $i_input == "Y" ];
                         then
                         mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
                         echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd >> ~/.restore.info
                         echo $filename has been deleted. Congrats.
                             else
                             echo Nothing has been done, the file or files remain.
                     fi
                else
                    read -p "Are you SURE you want to delete $filename ????" i_input
                    if [ $i_input == "y"  ] || [ $i_input == "Y" ];
                      then
                      mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
                      echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd >> ~/.restore.info
                         else
                         echo Aborted
                    fi
          fi
      elif $verbose
        then
         mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
         echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd >> ~/.restore.info
         echo $filename has been deleted. Congrats.
      else
         mv $filename ~/deleted/${filename}_$inode
         echo ${filename}_$inode:$pwd >> ~/.restore.info
         echo Executed
    fi
    }
    interactive=false
    verbose=false
    recursive=false
    while getopts ivr OPTION
    do
      case $OPTION in
        i) interactive=true;;
        v) verbose=true;;
        r) recursive=true;;
      esac
    done
    shift $[OPTIND-1]
    for i in $*
      do
    filename=$i
    basefile=$(basename $i)
    if [ "$i" == "" ];
       then
         echo No file provided
        elif [ -d $filename ];
         then
            if [ $recursive = true ];
               then
                 recur_delete $filename
               else
               echo This is a directory, please provide a file name.
            fi
       elif [ ! -f $filename ];
        then
         echo File does not exist
       elif [ "$basefile" == "safe_rm" ];
         then
          echo Attempting to delete safe_rm - operation aborted!!!!
    #This is the line that takes the filename to be deleted and modifies the
    #experience based on what the user wants.
    else
       delete_file $filename
    fi
    done
```

Comment: Rule 1 of writing any shell script: Quote your variables. Do that then try again and see if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems super-complicated.  How about building something around

```
$ mkdir ~/.trashbin
$ mv /absolute/path/to/dir/or/file ~/.trashbin
```

for temp delete and then

```
$ mv ~/.trashbin/absolute/path/to/dir /absolute/path/to/dir
```

for restore?

You need one little fragment of code to get the old absolute path with the ~/.trashbin deleted, but that's simple.

**Update**

Aaah, it's the silly professor problem. I resemble that.

Okay, here's the deal: in any recursion, there has to be something that "gets smaller" in some sense with each call, and finally gets to the point where you stop recurring.  In your case, that should be the results of `ls -A`. Step away from the code and examine what you *really* get from `ls -A` on an empty directory, and whether that evaluates to 0 or non-zero in that if.  Hint: I bet it never does.

Comment: I wish I could make it simpler, but this is what my professor wants. My delete function works, the problem is my recur_delete function that puts me in an infinite loop. I'm not sure where or why it's doing it.